# Putty : connection timed out in public network (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ssh, putty

I need to ssh from my Windows laptop to an Ubuntu desktop using Putty, both connected to a residential wifi network (needs authentification in webpage).

I installed openssh-server and enabled port 22, but I can neither ping nor ssh between client and host.

The connection works pretty well (including ping) when connecting both client and host to smartphone internet.

Anyone managed to ssh in a public network (college, airport...)?

**Edit** (things tested from discussions):

- Public IP address is not the same as the local IP (that I get from `ifconfig`) for both client and host
- I can ssh 127.0.0.1
- Port forwarding 127.0.0.1:22 to the local ip adress with virtualbox worked. I tried Webmin, but didn't work for me (maybe the config. was wrong).

Comment: My public ip adress is not the same as the local ip (that i get from ifconfig) for both client and host. For ssh I was using the local ip that i got from ifconfig

Comment: Yes I can ssh 127.0.0.1, i thought about using port forwarding (like in virtualbox) using webmin, but it didn't work. Using virtualbox in windows laptop works fine !

Comment: Port forwarding 127.0.0.1:22 to the local ip adress in the vrtualbox worked. Is it possible to apply the same method to the ubuntu desktop ?

Comment: can we use ipv4 dns servers ip for port forwarding (found it in the network properties)

Comment: The extra details included here in comments would be useful if edited into the question - that will attract the most useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your wireless network is set up in isolation mode, meaning clients purposefully cannot see each other.  This is to prevent folks from setting up sub-networks, or trying to use a wifi IP to connect to a physical network device.

Your only real option is to connect both clients to a VPN hub, and interconnect via ssh over the VPN.